# Why does define range with cell.address work but not cell only Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

I'm trying to work out how to apply a formula to a range of cells that is defined based on the Range.End method explained [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/).

I've avoided Select etc. as per [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

I've used the code below earlier on with regards to Range(Cells, Cells) and I had the desired output of copying an unknown number of rows dataset in column B related to a particular search entry for data in column A.

```
Set CopyFrom1 = Cells(FirstRow, "B")    
Set CopyFrom2 = Cells(LastRow, "B")

sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(CopyFrom1, CopyFrom2).Copy _
    destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6")
```

Now the dataset is copied across to destBook, I want to apply a formula to it. However, I don't know how many rows it is, so I use the Range(Cells, Cells) method again.

```
LRow = destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set LRowA = Cells(LRow, "D")
Set FRowA = Cells(6, "D")
destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(LRowA, FRowA).Formula = "=C6*2.236936"
```

This resulted in: *run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.*

I tried this method of qualifying Cells [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells), since the VBA code is running from the sourceBook and I'm working in destBook (different Workbook). However, I get *run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method*. I don't quite understand what's different here in comparison to what I'm trying to achieve.

Just before posting this, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030763/7199404, which gave me the result I needed. Code below:

```
destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(LRowA.Address, FRowA.Address).Formula = "=C6*2.236936"
```

Could someone please explain to me why this works and the others do not?

Comment: `Cells(LRow, "D")` and `Cells(6, "D")` are implicitly referring to the active worksheet. Hence you can only use them to define a range on the active worksheet. If that's not `destBook.Sheets("Sheet1")`, then things go boom. Which part is unclear?

Comment: OK, I understand now how to explicitly define the object. For instance, `destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LRow, "D")`.

Why does the last line above work though with `.Address`? Is it doing the same thing or something different?

Comment: After your clarification and reviewing [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) again, I now understand what the answer is trying to describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the range can make it easier:

```
Set rngFrom = sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FirstRow, "B" & LastRow)
Set rngTo = destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6").Resize(rngFrom.Rows.Count)

rngTo.Value = rngFrom.Value
rngTo.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=C6*2.236936"
```

Comment: My understanding is that this answer is an efficient method of writing VBA in comparison to my answer, correct?

Comment: Yes, but use whatever is easier to maintain. I don't think the difference in speed will be noticeable. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=201611241506412220564

Answer (score 0):

The correct code in this case is

```
Set LRowA = destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LRow, "D")
Set FRowA = destBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, "D")
```

An explanation can be found here: [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) and further clarity from Mat's Mug comment above.